# Validate textbox charset for zeros and ones

Tags: character-encoding, binary

I'm trying to check if the charset of textbox1 contains binary, but sadly this doesn't work. Any help appreciated...

```
Dim binarycheck As Boolean
If binarycheck = textbox1.Text Like "[0-1]" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Already in binary form!")
end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Regex.IsMatch(inputString, "^[01]+$");
```

Comment: Thanks! it says 'regex is not declared' (sorry I'm a complete noob).

Comment: For VB.net you need this at the beginning: Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Comment: Some examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly!! I appreciate your help. Been tearing my hairs out :)